# Trying to loop over bootstrap rows, to add 3 col-4's in each using DOM

Tags: javascript, for-loop, bootstrap-4

So I'm basically pulling from a Studio Ghibli API, and outputting data in bootstrap cards from the info it gets me. That part works, but I want them to align in rows of 3 col-md-4's.

Here's my for loop:

```js
for (let col in row) {
      let newRow = document.createElement("div");
      newRow.setAttribute("class", "row");
      container.appendChild(newRow);
      for (col = 0; col <= 3; col++) {
        newCol[col].appendChild(card.appendChild(cardBody));
        cardBody.appendChild(cardTitle);
        cardBody.appendChild(cardSubtitle);
        cardBody.appendChild(cardText);
      }
    }
```

I basically get an endless loop creating thousands of "rows", but without my "cols" inside/data. And for any clarification here is the rest of the file:

```js
const row = document.querySelector(".row");
const container = document.querySelector(".container");
// const col = document.getElementById("col-md-4");

fetch("https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/films")
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    displayResults(data);
  })
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));

function displayResults(data) {
  for (results of data) {
    // new col
    let newCol = document.createElement("div");
    newCol.setAttribute("class", "col-md-4");

    // card
    let card = document.createElement("div");
    card.setAttribute("class", "card");
    card.style.width = "18rem";

    // card body
    let cardBody = document.createElement("div");
    cardBody.setAttribute("class", "card-body");

    // card title
    let cardTitle = document.createElement("h5");
    cardTitle.setAttribute("class", "card-title");
    cardTitle.innerHTML = results.title;

    // card subtitle
    let cardSubtitle = document.createElement("h6");
    cardSubtitle.setAttribute("class", "card-subtitle mb-2");
    cardSubtitle.innerHTML = "-" + results.director;

    // card text
    let cardText = document.createElement("p");
    cardText.setAttribute("class", "card-text");
    cardText.innerHTML = results.description;
```

And HTML is fairly simple:

```html
 <div class="container">
      <div class="row"></div>
    </div>
```

EDIT: I left out all the boiler plate HTML/bootstrap import code.

Comment: Can you please share the HTML code too?

Comment: Just updated it

Answer (score 0):

Check out this approach which makes use of a string literal instead of creating elements dynamically.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div id="card-selector" class="row">
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
 const row = document.querySelector(".row");
 const container = document.querySelector(".container");

    fetch("https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/films")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then(function (data) {
        displayResults(data);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));

    function displayResults(data) {
      const cardSelector = document.getElementById("card-selector");
      data.forEach((result) => {
        let card = `
                  <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <h5 class="card-title">${result.title}</h5>
                      <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                    </div>
                  </div>`;

        let containerDiv = document.createElement("div"); //create the col div
        containerDiv.setAttribute("class", "col-sm-6 col-md-4"); //Add the bootstrap col class as needed
        containerDiv.innerHTML = card;
        cardSelector.appendChild(containerDiv);
      });
    }
```

```js
const row = document.querySelector(".row");
 const container = document.querySelector(".container");

    fetch("https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/films")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then(function (data) {
        displayResults(data);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));

    function displayResults(data) {
      const cardSelector = document.getElementById("card-selector");
      data.forEach((result) => {
        let card = `
                  <div class="card mb-3">
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <h5 class="card-title">${result.title}</h5>
                      <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                    </div>
                  </div>`;

        let containerDiv = document.createElement("div"); //create the col div
        containerDiv.setAttribute("class", "col-sm-6 col-md-4"); //Add the bootstrap col class as needed
        containerDiv.innerHTML = card;
        cardSelector.appendChild(containerDiv);
      });
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div id="card-selector" class="row">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you that worked, just need to review it.